# MySQL merge multiple queries for report

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, aggregate-functions

See SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bb273

I need to create a report out of 3 queries. It needs to be a single query without subqueries (due to ORM limitations).

The main query is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
Organization.name as organization_name, 
Program.unique_id as program_uuid, 
Program.name as program_name,
Program.start_date,
Program.end_date,
Program.grace_period,
'Placeholder A' as 'Participant Count',
'Placeholder B' as 'Total Participant Points',
count(distinct Transaction.id) as 'Transaction Count',
sum(TransactionItem.quantity) as 'Total Redemptions',
sum(((TransactionProduct.retail + IFNULL(TransactionProduct.shipping,0) + IFNULL(TransactionProduct.handling,0)) * TransactionItem.quantity)) as 'Total'
FROM `TransactionItem` 
JOIN `Transaction` ON `Transaction`.id = `TransactionItem`.transaction_id 
JOIN `TransactionProduct` ON `TransactionItem`.reference_id = `TransactionProduct`.reference_id 
JOIN `Participant` ON `Transaction`.participant_id = `Participant`.id 
JOIN `Program` ON `Program`.id = `Participant`.program_id 
JOIN `Organization` ON `Organization`.id = `Participant`.organization_id 
WHERE 1=1  
AND `Organization`.`unique_id` = 'demo2' 
AND `Program`.`unique_id` = 'demo2' 
AND `Transaction`.`created_at` >= '2018-10-01 00:00:00' 
AND `Transaction`.`created_at` <= '2018-12-18 00:00:00';
```

As you can see, this report is for the date range between 10/1 and 12/18. The result set that makes up the report is...

```
organization_name | program_uuid | program_name | start_date | end_date | grace_period | Participant Count | Total Participant Points | Transaction Count | Total Redemptions | Total
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Demo2 Org           demo2          Demo2          2018-10-01   2018-12-27  5             Placeholder A       Placeholder B              11                   92                 2853.13
```

As you can see, there are 2 data points that I'm unable to get from this query.

(1) The total number of participants belonging to the "demo2" Program. This query gets that data point.

```
/* Placeholder A */
select program_id, count(*) as 'Participant Count' from participant 
where active = 1
group by program_id;
```

Returns:

```
program_id   |  Participant Count
----------------------------------
2               102
```

(2) The sum of Adjustments.amount for all rows between dates 10/1 and 12/18. This query fulfills that.

```
/* Placeholder B */
select sum(amount) as 'Total Particpant Points' from adjustment 
where participant_id in (select id from participant where program_id =2)
and type = 1
and created_at >= '2018-10-01 00:00:00' and created_at <= '2018-12-18 00:00:00';
```

Returns:

```
 Total Participant Points
 ------------------------
 10000.50000
```

Is there a way to gather all of this data in a single query without subqueries?

Comment: without table definition, sample data and expected results it is hard to help. What have you tried?

Comment: The first line of the question has the SQLFiddle with schema and test data.

Comment: You can use `OVER()` if your MySQL support it.

Comment: It does not. :(

Comment: Why don't you use a parametric stored procedure to get these results as atomic output.